# Ethereum's benefits: why should I be interested in Ethereum?

Tags: contract-development, dapps, dapp-development, trust, use-cases

Is there a list of features and benefits to using Ethereum?

As a developer, why should I spend time looking into Ethereum?

What engineering benefits does Ethereum offer over existing technologies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most official list must be the one in [the Ethereum book](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/ethereum.html):

- user authentication, via seamless integration of cryptographic signatures
- fully customizable payment logic; easily create your own payment system without any reliance on third parties
- 100% ddos resistant up-time, guaranteed by being a fully decentralized blockchain-based platform
- no-fuss storage: forget about having to set up secure databases; Ethereum gives you as much storage as you want
- ultimate interoperability: everything in the Ethereum ecosystem can trivially interact with everything else, from reputation to custom currencies
- server free zone: your whole application can be deployed on the blockchain meaning no need for setting up or maintaining servers; let your users pay for the cost of their using your service.

If you prefer video to text, can you see [this short video: Ethereum the world computer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j23HnORQXvs).